# How to convert string to integer in UNIX shelll

Tags: linux, shell, unix, interactive

I have `d1="11"` and `d2="07"`. I want to convert `d1` and `d2` to integers and perform `d1-d2`. How do I do this in UNIX?

`d1 - d2` currently returns `"11-07"` as result for me.

Comment: Did you want this from the command line or programatically?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The standard solution:

```
 expr $d1 - $d2
```

You can also do:

```
echo $(( d1 - d2 ))
```

but beware that this will treat `07` as an octal number!  (so `07` is the same as `7`, but `010` is different than `10`).

Comment: Given that bash has syntax for specifying numeric base, why not demonstrate it here (albeit with a portability caveat)?

Comment: You can base-convert: `echo $((d1-10#$d2))`

Beware: it is not the same than `echo $((d1-10#d2))`

Comment: Given that bash is NOT the standard and isn't guaranteed on all targets...how about skipping the bash-isms since they didn't ask how to do it in bash...?

Comment: Be careful if your variables can hold non-integer strings or if you are using options `nounset` and `errexit` (which you should always use). I have written many tests for different scenarios in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59781257/117471

Comment: You should definitely be wary of non-integer values, and using `nounset` is often a good idea.  But you should *never* use `errexit`.

Answer (score 24):

Any of these will work from the shell command line. `bc` is probably your most straight forward solution though.

Using [bc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bc):

```
$ echo "$d1 - $d2" | bc
```

Using `awk`:

```
$ echo $d1 $d2 | awk '{print $1 - $2}'
```

Using `perl`:

```
$ perl -E "say $d1 - $d2"
```

Using `Python`:

```
$ python -c "print $d1 - $d2"
```

all return

```
4
```

Comment: Not sure if it is a bug or a feature of `expr`, `awk`, `bc`, and `dc`, but all of those tools handle the case `d1=09` by treating 09 as the decimal value 9.  However, `perl` and `python` treat it as a syntax error.  You get different results for the case `d1=010`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Interesting .. I'll have to look into this, useful info, thanks.

Comment: You can do it straight away with pure Bash: `echo $((d1-10#$d2))`

Answer (score 10):

## An answer that is not limited to the OP's case

The title of the question leads people here, so I decided to answer that question for everyone else since the OP's described case was so limited.

### TL;DR

I finally settled on writing a function.

1. If you want `0` in case of non-int:

```sh
int(){ printf '%d' ${1:-} 2>/dev/null || :; }
```

2. If you want *[empty_string]* in case of non-int:

```sh
int(){ expr 0 + ${1:-} 2>/dev/null||:; }
```

3. If you want find the first int or *[empty_string]*:

```sh
int(){ expr ${1:-} : '[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)' 2>/dev/null||:; }
```

4. If you want find the first int or 0:

```sh
# This is a combination of numbers 1 and 2
int(){ expr ${1:-} : '[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)' 2>/dev/null||:; }
```

If you want to get a non-zero status code on non-int, remove the `||:` (aka or `true`) but leave the `;`

### Tests

```sh
# Wrapped in parens to call a subprocess and not `set` options in the main bash process
# In other words, you can literally copy-paste this code block into your shell to test
( set -eu;
    tests=( 4 "5" "6foo" "bar7" "foo8.9bar" "baz" " " "" )
    test(){ echo; type int; for test in "${tests[@]}"; do echo "got '$(int $test)' from '$test'"; done; echo "got '$(int)' with no argument"; }

    int(){ printf '%d' ${1:-} 2>/dev/null||:; };
    test

    int(){ expr 0 + ${1:-} 2>/dev/null||:; }
    test

    int(){ expr ${1:-} : '[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)' 2>/dev/null||:; }
    test

    int(){ printf '%d' $(expr ${1:-} : '[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)' 2>/dev/null)||:; }
    test

    # unexpected inconsistent results from `bc`
    int(){ bc<<<"${1:-}" 2>/dev/null||:; }
    test
)
```

### Test output

```sh
int is a function
int ()
{
    printf '%d' ${1:-} 2> /dev/null || :
}
got '4' from '4'
got '5' from '5'
got '0' from '6foo'
got '0' from 'bar7'
got '0' from 'foo8.9bar'
got '0' from 'baz'
got '0' from ' '
got '0' from ''
got '0' with no argument

int is a function
int ()
{
    expr 0 + ${1:-} 2> /dev/null || :
}
got '4' from '4'
got '5' from '5'
got '' from '6foo'
got '' from 'bar7'
got '' from 'foo8.9bar'
got '' from 'baz'
got '' from ' '
got '' from ''
got '' with no argument

int is a function
int ()
{
    expr ${1:-} : '[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)' 2> /dev/null || :
}
got '4' from '4'
got '5' from '5'
got '6' from '6foo'
got '7' from 'bar7'
got '8' from 'foo8.9bar'
got '' from 'baz'
got '' from ' '
got '' from ''
got '' with no argument

int is a function
int ()
{
    printf '%d' $(expr ${1:-} : '[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)' 2>/dev/null) || :
}
got '4' from '4'
got '5' from '5'
got '6' from '6foo'
got '7' from 'bar7'
got '8' from 'foo8.9bar'
got '0' from 'baz'
got '0' from ' '
got '0' from ''
got '0' with no argument

int is a function
int ()
{
    bc <<< "${1:-}" 2> /dev/null || :
}
got '4' from '4'
got '5' from '5'
got '' from '6foo'
got '0' from 'bar7'
got '' from 'foo8.9bar'
got '0' from 'baz'
got '' from ' '
got '' from ''
got '' with no argument
```

### Note

I got sent down this rabbit hole because the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11269389/117471) is not compatible with `set -o nounset` (aka `set -u`)

```sh
# This works
$ ( number="3"; string="foo"; echo $((number)) $((string)); )
3 0

# This doesn't
$ ( set -u; number="3"; string="foo"; echo $((number)) $((string)); )
-bash: foo: unbound variable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let d=d1-d2;echo $d;
```

This should help.

Comment: This is effectively the same as `d=$(( d1 - d2 )); echo "$d"`, as covered by the accepted answer (with the same caveat that `0`-prefixed numbers are interpreted as _octals_).

Answer (score -10):

Use this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char *d1 = "11";
    int d1int = atoi(d1);
    printf("d1 = %d\n", d1);
    return 0;
}
```

etc.

Comment: qwarentine meant Linux shell.